# How to mask a geographic IP address on corporate VPN

Tags: vpn

My wife is working remote due to COVID for a company that has a policy in place to not work from outside of California for an extended period of time. She logs in via a corporate VPN using our home WiFi network.

We are moving from LA to Phoenix had she would like to hang on to her job until COVID is over.

Are there any options to mask the IP address of our Phoenix ISP?  I have read that one solution is the use of a VPN, but her company is already using one for her to log into her corporate environment. She has no admin access to her laptop.

Comment: Whats up with all the brand new accounts that keep asking this same question in the last couple weeks?

Comment: Maybe because working remotely has exploded under COVID?